# PowerBi: Query HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, powerbi, powerquery

**What I need**

I need to retrieve data from [this source](https://gee.bccr.fi.cr/indicadoreseconomicos/Cuadros/frmVerCatCuadro.aspx?idioma=1&CodCuadro=%20400) . Let's assume I must use only PowerBi for this.

**What I did so far**

If I use the basic web source option, then the query is just basically an htlm parsing with which I can easily get the data found in the html scope of the page, example:

Source:

[image]

The steps I'm following through Web source option:

[image]

[image]

Query:

[image]

(to simplify the example, assume we don't need the dates)

You can download that example .pbix file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GJ8O0kDklzl3GUoX8dQE7KWTojQbEByv/view?usp=sharing).

**The problem**

The problem is that I need more data, which can't be accessed through the html preview. For example, let's imagine I need to retrieve the data from January 2010 to April 2020. Those king of queries can only be done via this button located in the webpage (which exports the requested data to an Excel workbook):

[image]

The idea is to get this process automated, so going to the source and export the excel file all the time is not an option.

Inspecting the element I realized that what it does is execute a javascript function:

[image]

**The question**

As a PowerBi/PowerQuery noob I wonder: Is there any way I can get that data directly with PowerBi (maybe calling the js function somehow)? If there is so, then how?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my case was to use URL parameters to retrieve de data without parsing the html table.

❌Original URL I was using:

https://gee.bccr.fi.cr/indicadoreseconomicos/Cuadros/frmVerCatCuadro.aspx?idioma=1&CodCuadro=%20400

✔️New URL for the query, adding some parameters:

https://gee.bccr.fi.cr/indicadoreseconomicos/Cuadros/frmVerCatCuadro.aspx?idioma=1&CodCuadro=%20400&Idioma=1&FecInicial=2010/01/01&FecFinal=2040/01/01&Filtro=0&Exportar=True

This procedure only works in this case, because obviously the parameters will not be the same on other web pages.

However, I post this answer to keep the main idea for those who are in a similar situation: first try with the appropriate url parameters to get the data in a different format. Of course you first must know which are the available parameters, which is a limitation.